# back button issue after opening a page over photoswipe carousel

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

i have a similar problem like this

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqm-1-0a3-dialog-url-state-appears-in-history

i am using photoswipe + jquerymobile + phonegap, the issue is when the gallery loads and i click on any image which takes me to carousel mode now from here if i goto another page and click back button this occures at the end of the url in the browser address bar

## &ui-state=dialog

but it does not goes back to the carousel mode.so when i click again back button it takes me to the gallery page skipping the carousel mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to do: 1) remove the ps-active class from the body tag 2) find all photoswipe instances and unset them

The following code worked for me:

```
 $(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e) {
 if ($('.ps-carousel').length) {
  $('body').removeClass('ps-active');
  $('div.gallery-page').each(function(){
    var photoSwipe = window.Code.PhotoSwipe;
    var photoSwipeInstance = photoSwipe.getInstance($(this).attr('id'));
    if (typeof photoSwipeInstance != "undefined" && photoSwipeInstance != null) {
        photoSwipe.unsetActivateInstance(photoSwipeInstance);
     }
   });
 }
  });
```

Please check this **[link](https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/issues/375)** for more information .

Comment: let me define the scenario,on the carousel (slide show mode) i have an extra button Preview so when i click on that it takes me to new page where that image is shown,now when i try to get back to the slideshow it fails.

i dont have a back button on the Preview page i use browser's back button or android's back button when testing in google nexus.

Comment: i tried that snippet it is also not taking me on carousel seems like there is no back history created.

Comment: this also dont work in my case :( i dont want to unset the photoswipe instances i want to goback to the carousel mode where toolbar is displayed.

Comment: Hi check this post same issue fixed and working , it may be useful to you..... `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089688/photoswipe-jqm-back-event-issue`

Comment: thanks for your time,

this was the solution to my problem,
https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/issues/373

i got some other minor issues but i hope i can fix those.